# how to set 15 textfield in one viewcontroller using scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiscrollview

What I have is 15 text field and because of which I can't set them in one ViewController. I added 15 textfield to the scrollview . But scroll view goes up on removing finger from the screen.

Any idea how to stick to down when scrolled to down?

Comment: give some code else its difficult

Comment: My first guess is, your are not setting contentSize of your scrollview correctly

Comment: You can make textField like this http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/09/make-label-and-button.html

Comment: set the content size of the scroll view.

Comment: put screen shot of this

Comment: Why not use a tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `ViewWillApear` Set your `UIScrollview`  `contentSize` like:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

     srcScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

and your TextFiled Delegate look like :-

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(FMTextField *)textField
{
    [srcScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textField.center.y-140) animated:YES];


}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

     [srcScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: check my Updated Answer my friend :)

Comment: Now I have another problem. I have navigation bar. I have scroll view at x=0,y=150, but still it shows at 0,0 in iphone

Comment: I have dragged scroll view at position 0,150. When i run, i see scroll view from 0,0 and not at 0,0

Comment: still i am not getting but may be issue is you can set ScrollView Frame programeticuly in ViewwillApear also

Comment: what I wanted to do is put scroll view from x=0 and y=100. how to do that programatically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25586/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-fahim-parkar)

Comment: self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(150.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You have to correctly set the `contentSize` of your scrollView. In your case you just have to set the content height to :

```
lastTextField.frame.origin.y + lastTextField.frame.size.height + 10
```

where 10 is the bottom margin you want.

Answer (score 0):

Below solved the problem...

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1200)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your contentSize is not big enough to display whole content. Set the contensize as the following

```
//Assuming you have a reference to the 15th textField 

CGRect textField15Frame = self.textField15.frame;

CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
contentSize.height = textField15Frame.origin.y+textField15.size.height+5.0f;

[self.scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```